# WCF Service returning HTTP 405 in a POST

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm facing the folowing situation: When I call a WCF Service with GET (getUserByUID) the service returns the correct data. When I call InsertUser the server returns HTTP error 405 Method not allowed.

I think it can be a Server configuration problem. I've already googled a lot and didn't find a solution.

The environment is Win2008R2 with IIS7.5

Thank you in advance,

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IUserService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "GetUserById?x={uid}")]
    User getUserByUID(string uid);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "InsertUser")]
    string InsertUser(User user);
```

Comment: Can you show your `web.config` ?

Answer (score 0):

@Mairaj Ahmad thank you for trying to help.

I found the error. I had WebDAV Handler Mapper in the IIS even after I remove it from IIS.

I deleted the entry and the service worked.